# Accessing empty string after calling table()

Tags: r

Here is the repro code:

```
> example <- c("", "", "a", "b", "c")
> t <- table(example)
> t
example
  a b c 
2 1 1 1 
> t[""]
<NA> 
  NA
```

I am trying to access the number of strings in my array that are empty.

I know there are some hacky workarounds (like replacing the empty strings in the original array) but am I missing something here?

Comment: I don't think the empty string is a valid name: `c("" = 2)`

Comment: You can do matching manually: `t[match("", names(t))]`

Comment: You can do it, again indirectly, using `t[dimnames(t)[[1]] == '']`.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comment you can acess an empty string

```
d[['']]
Error in d[[""]] : subscript out of bounds
> d[['a']]
[1] 1
```

As a workaround, you can much by yourself using names(d)  or You can coerce the result to a data.frame

```
dat <- data.frame(d)
> dat[1,]
  example Freq
1            2
```